# « Ça l’écœure (de) se faire reprendre par un étudiant »

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, reformulation

Dit-on plutôt :

> Ça l’écœure se faire reprendre par un étudiant.

ou

> Ça l’écœure **de** se faire reprendre par un étudiant.

N’hésitez pas à me donner d’autres propositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'usage est de mettre la préposition *de* :

> Ça l’écœure **de** se faire reprendre par un étudiant.

Si on n'en veut pas, on peut la remplacer par une pause :

> Ça l’écœure, se faire reprendre par un étudiant.

Cet usage d'[écœurer](https://www.je-parle-quebecois.com/lexique/definition/ecoeurer.html) est un québécisme. En France, on dirait plutôt :

> Ça le contrarie de se faire reprendre par un étudiant.

Comment: Je conçois bien que cela se dise à l’oral, mais à l’écrit, serait-ce considéré comme appartenant au registre familier?

Comment: *Ça le contrarie de se faire reprendre par un étudiant.* n'est pas de registre familier mais simplement courant. Si ta question concerne le verbe *écœurer*, je n'ai pas assez d'expérience en français québécois pour répondre.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Pour le registre, je vois [_écoeurer_](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/%C3%A9coeurer) comme plus familier, comme [_tanner_](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/tanner#contenu_sous_sens-197-9) et [_achaler_](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/achaler) d'ailleurs, sinon je vois _fatiguer, fâcher, déranger_, mais peut-être moins forts que ton choix. Un terme familier dans un discours plus courant peut créer un impact, dépendamment de comment tu prononcerais la phrase par exemple. Je trouve _contrarier_ riche ; peut-être _excéder_ aussi.

Comment: Étrange que tu dises qu'_écœurer_ soit utilisé en québécois dans cette expression. Ça me semblait bien français. D'ailleurs ça sonne plus fort avec _écœurer_ qu'avec _contrarier_.

Comment: @AlexisWilke C'est justement parce que le verbe *écœurer* est trop fort qu'il ne serait pas vraiment plausible dans cette phrase si elle était prononcée en France. On peut en revanche très bien dire en France: *Je suis écœuré par les propos de cet étudiant* (disgusted).

Answer (score -1):

La première phrase, sans préposition, n'est pas utilisée, sauf dans une langue parlée relâchée, mais une virgule peut être utilisée lorsque l'on écrit.

- Ça l'écœure, venir ici sans jouer.

La seconde construction (ça l'écœure de) ne se trouve pas ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A7a+l%27%C3%A9c%C5%93ure+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=)), mais  elle existe pour d'autres verbes comme « ennuyer », qui est un verbe très similaire, et donc elle est justifiée, et donne l'impression d'être naturelle.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/%C3%87a_n_a_aucun_sens/ASXdDAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A7a+l%27+ennuie+d%27%22&pg=PT168&printsec=frontcover)) « ça l'ennuie d'aller au contact des gens. »

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Pavane_pour_l_amour_manqu%C3%A9_Couleur_de_s/AVdtDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A7a+l%27+ennuie+de%22&pg=PT361&printsec=frontcover)) Non, ça l'ennuie de me ramener à L., ça l'ennuie de m'inviter, il est de mauvaise humeur depuis mon arrivée, j'aime mieux partir.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_epoustouflante_Soeur_Charlotte_de_la_C/bP8KWeKGiI4C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A7a+l%27+ennuie+de%22&pg=PA74&printsec=frontcover)) Comme il travaille dans le service topographique de la ville d'à côté, ça l'ennuie de rejoindre sa femme tous les soirs.

Les formulations suivantes préservent la simplicité de l'énoncé.

- Se faire reprendre par un étudiant l'écœure.
- Il est écœuré à l'idée de se faire reprendre par un étudiant. (*Plutôt une assertion générale*)
- Il est écœuré de se faire reprendre par un étudiant. (*Plutôt ce que l'on dira après une occasion de s'être  fait reprendre ainsi; aussi « de s'être fait reprendre »*)

La référence suivant est un exemple parmi de nombreux autre montrant l'utilisation de « de » avec ce verbe.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&hl=fr&q=%22est+%C3%A9c%C5%93ur%C3%A9+de)) Paul est écœuré de découvrir la véritable essence de cette petite femme qui semblait si parfaite.

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Je m'en suis remis  à Google pour cette assertion / https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A7a+l%27%C3%A9c%C5%93ure+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url= . Néanmoins, je ne me base pas là-dessus comme preuve que ça n'existerait pas et j'affirme que c'est correct (parce que, tout d'abord, ça me semble naturel).